# Importing Denormalized data into django models via modelforms

Tags: python, django, django-models, import, flat-file

## The Scenario:

I have some data that looks a bit like this:

```
Person   | Favorite Color | Favorite Fruit
------------------------------------------
Bobby    | RED            | BANANA
Jared    | YELLOW         | RASPBERRY
Milly    | BLACK          | PEACH
Shawn    | ORANGE         | ORANGE
```

Assume it's in a flatfile, or python dicts, or some other non-sql format.

EDIT:  Assume for the sake of argument that I've already got it in a Python structure that looks like this:

```
data = [
    {"name": "Bobby", "favorite_color": "RED", "favorite_fruit": "BANANA"},
    {"name": "Jared", "favorite_color": "YELLOW", "favorite_fruit": "RASPBERRY"},
    # etc....
 ]
```

I have django models that look like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    COLORS = (
                 ('R', 'RED'),
                 ('O', 'ORANGE'),
                 ('Y', 'YELLOW'),
                 ('G', 'GREEN'),
                 ('B', 'BLUE'),
                 ('P', 'PURPLE'),
                 ('L', 'BLACK'),
                 ('W', 'WHITE')
              )
    name = CharField(max_length=256)
    favorite_color = CharField(max_length=1, choices=COLORS)
    favorite_fruit = ForeignKey(Fruit)

class Fruit(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=256)
    fructose_content = PositiveIntegerField()
```

EDIT: Assume that my `Fruit` model is already populated with all the possible fruits.

## The task:

I would like to import my data from the original source into my Django models by using `ModelForm`s, to take advantage of proper validation and database abstraction.

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
```

Is there a way the `ModelForm` can translate the denormalized data into data that can be saved in the model?  Are `ModelForm`s the wrong thing to use here?

Comment: Why do you need to use ModelForm? Can't you just implement a script to populate objects directly calling save() for each one?

Comment: First, because it was recommended in most of the literature I've read (_two_scoops_of_django_, e.g.).  Second, because I would like to take advantage of built-in validation for other fields (obviously my real-world data is much more complex than the example.  Third, because I have maybe a dozen different tables/models to import, and I want a way to abstract the unique transformations on each one so the main import script can just loop through them and call `is_valid` and `save` to validate, transform, and save the data.  Is `ModelForm` the wrong place to do that?

Comment: I think I don't understand your scenario well. With forms you can validate data and are used mainly on requests, eg: web or api. If you need to populate your models from a text file I don't see the advantage of using forms. You can display the exceptions when saving and do something accordingly.

Comment: OK, what you want can be done and I will answer your question, just wanted to make sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a partial solution, at least for the problem involving the choices.  I guess with some tinkering it could work for `ForeignKey` fields as well.

First, I define a function `get_choice_by_name` which goes through a choices tuple and looks for a key by value.

Then I subclassed `TypedChoiceField` and overrode its `clean()` method to transform the data.  This method seems to get called before any validation.

Here's the code:

```
def get_choice_by_name(name, choices, case_sensitive=False):
    try:
        if name is None:
            return ''
        elif name and not case_sensitive:
            return next(k for k, n in choices
                        if n.lower() == name.lower())
        else:
            return next(k for k, n in choices if n == name)
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError(
            "Invalid choice: {}, not found in {}".format(name, choices)
        )

class DenormalizedChoiceField(TypedChoiceField):

    def clean(self, value):
        if not value:
            return self.empty_value
        try:
            value = get_choice_by_name(value, self.choices)
        except ValueError as e:
            raise ValidationError(str(e))

        value = super(DenormalizedChoiceField, self).clean(value)
        return value
```

My `ModelForm` now just needs to redefine the fields in question as `DenormalizedChoiceField`.  I need to specify the choices explicitly, though, for some reason it doesn't pick this up from the model if you override the field.

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    favorite_color = DenormalizedChoiceField(choices=Person.COLORS)
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
insert_data = []

with open('data.txt') as f:
    state = 'HEADER'
    headers = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        if state == 'HEADER':
            headers = [header.lower().strip().replace(' ', '_') for header in line.split('|')]
            state = 'IGNORE'
        elif state == 'IGNORE':
            state = 'DATA'
        elif state == 'DATA':
            data_values = map(str.strip, line.split('|'))
            insert_entry = {}
            for key, data in zip(headers, data_values):
                insert_entry[key] = data
            insert_data.append(insert_entry)

for row in insert_data:
    form = PersonForm(row)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    else:
        print form.errors()
```

The first step is to read the file (assuming it is named data.txt), I recommend you using json or some other structured text to avoid typing errors as you can check first if the file is well formatted using well-known libraries.

For this script to work, you will also need a trick for the fields in your forms, I think it will be enough calling the PERSON field as NAME.

On the second step we create the forms instances for every entry we want to insert, validate them and if everything is OK, we save them into the database.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks, but transforming the header names is not really the problem I'm trying to solve.  The problem is that the data for favorite_color and favorite_fruit in the dataset are denormalized, and the form isn't going to accept "ORANGE" or "BLACK" as a favorite color value, it wants "O" or "L".  LIkewise, favorite_fruit won't accept "BANANA" or "RASPBERRY", it wants an instance (or maybe an id?) for a `Fruit` object.  This is the problem I'm trying to solve, and I need to solve it in a generalized way (ie. not specific to this contrived data).

Comment: I've edited my original question to clarify the starting point of the incoming data.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So we have two problems:
a) Converting from model verbose names like ORANGE to "O" or from BLACK to "B"
b) Converting from names like BANANA or RASPBERRY to Fruit.

Comment: One way to solve the problem a) is to save into the database the same names you display, that way when you save a BLACK, the correct name is black indeed.

To solve problem b) see that for example you can save two fruits with the same name and it will make things even more difficult. You can save the fruit name as the key for the database by setting primary_key attribute as true and then you can set the foreign key on the form value.